# Laravel middleware gives an error when i use Auth::check() at middleware

Tags: laravel-5, routes, laravel-middleware

I am using laravel 5.5.

I use `!Auth::check()` in the middleware to check if user is logged in or not, but it shows an error like below:
at => /Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php
$response->headers->setCookie
Trying to get property of non-object
[image: Error when i try to access the route]

My admin middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (!Auth::check()) {
        return "Permission Denied.";
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

My kernel.php

```
'admin' => [
       \App\Http\Middleware\Admin::class,
    ]
```

My route file:

```
Route::get( '/', function () {
 return view( 'welcome' );
} )->middleware(['admin']);
```

Comment: Hi, Mahbubur 
in your route replace 'admin' to 'auth:admin'
hope that help

Answer (score 0):

For middleware expected to return instance of response object not a string.
Instead you should do

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (!Auth::check()) {
        return response('Permission Denied.', 401);
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```